# comparing sub-list elements in list using python

Tags: python, list

i have a list a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] and i need to check if all elements in sublist are in ascending order (e.g [1,2] is less than [3,4] and [5,6], and [3,4] is less than [5,6] and so on).
i use the following function:

```
def FirstRuleLink (L):
    for i in range(0,len(L)):
        for j in range(0,len(L[i])):
            if L[i][0]<L[i+1][0] and L[i][1]<L[i+1][1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

but the python gives me error message that index is out of range. so how could i change this code to get the correct output.

Comment: Why not just `L == sorted(L)`?

Comment: how do you think comparing `[1, 2]` to `[3, 4]` should work?

Comment: See point #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37620170/9209546).

Comment: sorted would not check both element of the sublist I think

Comment: @p.deman right, it may or may not work depending on what OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a try :

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

def FirstRuleLink (a):
    for i,nxt_elmnt in zip(a, a[1:]):
        if i[0] <= nxt_elmnt[0] and i[1] <= nxt_elmnt[1]:
            pass
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko thanks for finding mistakes, please take a look and let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: I would go with `all(list(t) == sorted(t) for t in zip(*a))`. Both this and your solution differs from OPs intention of using strict inequalities. Also, you probably mean to `return True` after the for loop.