# Unexpected pandas index error when using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the shape - `(133, 6)`
-   and I am trying to use iloc to iterate down the frame then select and append chunks of data to a list.

I have a list of start positions:

```
start_positions = [6, 32, 58, 84, 110]
```

and the end positions are +7 rows, so I have tried this:

```
frames = []
for x in start_positions:
    frames.append(df.iloc[start_positions[x] : start_positions[x]+7])
```

However is throwing:

`IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5`

Which I don’t quite understand as this works if I manually increment through `start_positions`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve out of this code @Maverick?

Comment: Each of the chunks represents a year of data and each column represents a different category. So the aim is to pull out the data and store it in separate locations corresponding to the year.

Comment: `for x in start_positions:` x are *not indices*! You use `start_positions[x]` , thus you see your error. Forget the dataframe, your issue occurs with you trying to index the list itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Loop: List Index Out of Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619848/python-loop-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1):

The code has problem right from the start in the for loop I think.  Look at `start_positions[x]` in `frames.append(df.iloc[start_positions[x] : start_positions[x]+7])`. The value of `x` in the for loop starts from 6 but the maximum index `start_positions`can have is 4 since `len(start_positions)=5`

@Maverick , I think what you may want to do is remove `start_positions` and have something like this (but didnt test the code)

```
for x in start_positions:
    frames.append(df.iloc[x : x+7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `for x in range(len(start_positions))` instead of `for x in start_positions` as:

```
frames = []
for x in range(len(start_positions)):
    print(start_positions[x],":",start_positions[x]+7)
```

It results:

```
6 : 13
32 : 39
58 : 65
84 : 91
110 : 117
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to use:

```
frames = []
for x in start_positions:
    frames.append(df.iloc[x:x+7])
```

x is an element of start_positions and can be accessed as is, had it been an index it would be used the way you did.