# List index out of range error when iterating Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am using a for loop to iterate through a pandas dataframe and append values to separate lists to then convert back to another pandas df. However, I am receiving an index out of range error when trying to call a value that has been previously appended to a list in the same iteration. NOTE: all lists (date, dow, rt, etc.) have been initialized prior to this code. Didn't want to make the post too long.

Here's my code:

```
#Iterrate through df to append to initialized lists
#list.append: O(log^2(n)) vs df.append: O(n^2)
#Append to lists then create df2 with completed lists
for i, row in df.iterrows():
        date.append(str(df.at[i, 'Route Date'])[0:10])
        dow.append(str(df.at[i, 'Route Number'])[0])
        rt.append(str(df.at[i, 'Route Number'])[1:4])
        #Append route type and municipality using lookup table
        #Lookup table will be packaged with PyInstaller
        for j, row in lookup.iterrows():
            if df.at[i, 'Route Number'] == lookup.at[j, 'Route']:
                rt_type.append(str(lookup.at[j, 'Route Type']))
                muni.append(str(lookup.at[j, 'Municipality']))
        miles.append(df.at[i, 'Miles'])
        disp_tons.append(df.at[i, 'Disposal Tons'])
        disp_loads.append(df.at[i, 'Disposal Loads'])
        stops.append(df.at[i, 'Stops'])
        clk_hrs.append(df.at[i, 'Clock Hours'])
        travel.append((miles[i]) / 22)
        #Service time varies by truck type and municipality
        if rt_type[i] == 'AFEL' and muni[i] == 'Vestavia Hills':
            service.append((stops[i]*17)/3600)
        disp.append((disp_loads[i])*(22/60))
        pre_post.append("0.78")
        target_clk_hrs.append(travel[i] + service[i] + disp[i] + 1.28)
        variance.append(target_clk_hrs[i] - clk_hrs[i])
        continue
```

The index error is occurring at `target_clk_hrs.append(travel[i] + service[i] + disp[i] + 1.28)` when calling the value of `service[i]`. When running this without the if statement: `if rt_type[i] == 'AFEL' and muni[i] == 'Vestavia Hills':` and instead using only `service.append((stops[i]*17)/3600)`, I run into no indexing errors. I am confused as to why A. this works without the if statement, and B. why `travel` doesn't run into an index error if `service` does.

I'm assuming the issue lies with the iterator `for j, row in lookup.iterrows()`. Note that `lookup` is a separate lookup table used to return values to some of the lists conditionally. I've tried using a break statement on this loop and am still getting the same error.

My other thought was that `rt_type[i]` and `muni[i]` in the if block are not being indexed correctly and therefore `service` is not being appended, but I haven't been able to come up with a fix for this.

I've also consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619848/why-do-i-get-list-index-out-of-range-when-trying-to-add-consecutive-numbers-in) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `i`-th step of the iteration `travel[i]` is the last element of `travel`, because your code guarantees exactly i insertions into `travel` up to the point.

However, insertions into `service` are conditional:

```
if rt_type[i] == 'AFEL' and muni[i] == 'Vestavia Hills':
    service.append((stops[i]*17)/3600)
```

When the condition is not satisfied, append doesn't happen and the potential length of the list shortens by 1.

Right after the first time the append doesn't happen `service` has length `i - 1`, so `service[i]` causes index error.

P.S. there're no examples of input and output, so it's hard to say, but probably your task could be solved in more pandas way, avoiding all the lists.

Comment: I've added elifs covering every permutation of `rt_type` and `muni`, as well as an else to append 'NaN' if no conditions are met, so append is guaranteed at each iteration. I'm now running into an index error at `rt_type[i] == 'AEFL' and muni[i] ...`. In the for loop to append `rt_type` and `muni`, I've added `else: continue` which should guarantee append, but obviously isn't. Any suggestions? Also, I'm dealing with lists due to time cost of growing an empty df using pandas. Appending the lists and zipping them to a df is much cheaper.

Comment: Update: I've found a discrepancy between df and my lookup table. This was causing indexes to be thrown off when this value wasn't found in the lookup. Currently kicking myself for not checking sooner... Thanks for the help!